# How to concatenate multiple netcdf files in to a single time series file?

Tags: python

I have downloaded monthly soil moisture data from year 2002 t0 2014. I want to merge all montly data(total 147 netcdf files) into a single netcdf time series data.
I got an error while i was trying in cdo.

**The files i have are like below:**

GLDAS_NOAH025_M.A200204.021.nc4.SUB.nc4

GLDAS_NOAH025_M.A200205.021.nc4.SUB.nc4

GLDAS_NOAH025_M.A200206.021.nc4.SUB.nc4

..

..

GLDAS_NOAH025_M.A201412.021.nc4.SUB.nc4

**The code i entered is:**

```
cdo mergetime GLDAS_*.nc4 merge_fie.nc4
```

**The error i encountered is:**
cdf_create        : ncid = -1  mode = 4096  file = merge_fie.nc4

cdf_create        : chunksizehint 0

Error (cdf_create): merge_fie.nc4: Permission denied

Error (cdf_close): NetCDF: HDF error

I am using Cygwin terminal for cdo command.

Comment: Have you investigated why this is the case? "Error (cdf_create): merge_fie.nc4: Permission denied"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I got it. Thanks. The problem was related with setting working directory permitted and readable by Cygwin (the place where i put my data was not connected to the terminal ).